# Reset setInterval() from object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am playing with VueJS and created a simple counter. I'd like to reset the `setInterval()` method from the `resetTimer()` function. However, it's not working. Not sure what I'm missing here.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0,
        counter: 0
    },
    methods: {
        timer() {
                setInterval(() => {
                    this.seconds = this.timerFormat(++this.counter % 60)
                    this.minutes = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60)
                    this.hours = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 3600, 10))
                }, 1000);
            },
            resetTimer() {
                clearInterval(this.timer())
            },
            timerFormat(timer) {
                return timer > 9 ? timer : '0' + timer;
            }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lean Vue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ hours }} : {{ minutes }} : {{ seconds }}</p>
      <button @click="timer">Start</button>
      <button @click="resetTimer">Pause</button>
    </div>

    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a global variable for the interval timer (`my_timer` in my example) then you could clear it in the reset action :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0,
        counter: 0,
        my_timer :0
    },
    methods: {
        timer() {
                this.my_timer = setInterval(() => {
                    this.seconds = this.timerFormat(++this.counter % 60)
                    this.minutes = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60)
                    this.hours = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 3600, 10))
                }, 1000);
            },
            pauseTimer() {
                clearInterval(this.my_timer)
            },
            timerFormat(timer) {
                return timer > 9 ? timer : '0' + timer;
            }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    counter: 0,
    my_timer:0
  },
  methods: {
    timer() {
      this.my_timer = setInterval(() => {
                                  this.seconds = this.timerFormat(++this.counter % 60)
      this.minutes = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60)
      this.hours = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 3600, 10))
    }, 1000);
  },
  resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.my_timer)
    this.hour=0
    this.minutes=0
    this.seconds=0
    this.counter=0
  },
  timerFormat(timer) {
    return timer > 9 ? timer : '0' + timer;
  }
}
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lean Vue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ hours }} : {{ minutes }} : {{ seconds }}</p>
      <button @click="timer">Start</button>
      <button @click="resetTimer">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be paused. I want to reset it and start from 0 again

Comment: But it doesn't. It just pauses the interval

Comment: Check my update, you've just to reset the other variable for the view...

Comment: haha, so the `clearInterval()` function won't reset the `setInterval()` counter to 0 then?

Comment: Yes, it reset the `my_timer` so the "`Interval`" stop looping so stop the `counter` from incrementing not reset it.

Comment: hmm, okay. that makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

Because `this.timer()` returns `undefined`.

Try this

```js
timer() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.seconds = this.timerFormat(++this.counter % 60)
            this.minutes = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60)
            this.hours = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 3600, 10))
        }, 1000);
}
```

And

```js
pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
 }
```

Comment: I already tried this by myself but it never resets the `setInterval()`. It just pauses the interval which seems very weird to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the time you are measuring, just set the values yourself:

```
this.hours = 0;
this.minutes = 0;
this.seconds = 0;
this.counter = 0;
```

You don't need clearInterval in this case.

NOTE: setInterval and clearInterval are not related to your own privately defined variable "counter" - so you need to handle it.

If you want to PAUSE the timer:

```
clearInterval(this.timer())
```

This invokes the timer() method again.

I think you wanted to save the returned value and then use it to clear the interval like so:

```
    timer() {
        this.intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
            this.seconds = this.timerFormat(++this.counter % 60)
            this.minutes = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60)
            this.hours = this.timerFormat(parseInt(this.counter / 3600, 10))
        }, 1000);
    },
    pauseTimer() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalTimer)
    },
```

Comment: I already tried this by myself but it never resets the `setInterval()`. It just pauses the interval which seems very weird to me

Comment: But what is your expectation when you say it should "reset the interval" ? Do you want your hours, minutes, seconds to be 0 again? that is a different problem - you just need to set them to 0 yourself e.g. `this.hours = 0; this.minutes=0; this.seconds = 0; this.counter = 0`

Comment: What I meant is I'd like the interval to start from 0 again

Comment: haha, so the `clearInterval()` function won't reset the `setInterval()` counter to 0 then?